# Splitting text attribute using conditional function QGIS 2.18.13

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression, conditional

I want to split a text column with city names by selecting only the names like `'world (planet)'` and not like `'world planet'`. Tried before with `left( "Name", strpos( "Name" ,' '))` update existing field and results are fine only for the names 'world (planet)' but the other names like 'world planet' disappeared from column, So tried with conditional function `case when 'names'like '%(%' then left( "Name", strpos( "Name" ,'')) end` (if this is a correct form of expression). Is there a way to split the names which is included the '()'?
(I'm new user in QGIS.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used only an opening brace `(` for this. Please let me know if this does not yield what you need.

```
left("Name" , strpos("Name" , '[(]')-2)
```

[image]

**EDIT** -------   to keep **(5)** `world ( planet` while cutting **(1)** `world (planet)`

```
CASE 
WHEN regexp_substr("Name", '(^.*\\s[(]\\S)') = left("Name", strpos("Name", '[(]')+1)
THEN left("Name" , strpos("Name" , '[(]')-2)
ELSE "Name"
END
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. The name 'world planet' and only the name 'world' its taken from 'world (planet)' in the same column. Thank you.

Comment: @indritleka Glad it worked out. Honestly I was uncertain about the problem you experienced. Let me upvote your question as soon as my daily limit recovers, so that it can get more proper attention.

Comment: checking the attribute table i found that some names like 'world i planet' the planet word disappear. I need another expression for those names i want to remain unchanged. So there are 'world planet' , 'world i planet' mby another like 'world i planet i world' and the last one that i want to split is 'world (planet)' . Can you help me with another expression? https://ibb.co/dC4iLG

Comment: @indritleka Thanks for your feed-back. Will certainly look at it. In the meantime will you un-accept this answer so that the others also can help you?

Comment: @indritleka Will you take a look at a syntax in the **EDIT** and see if it work? (Sorry, it is nasty. Hope someone gives you more sophisticated code).

Comment: Sorry for late reply. i tried this expression but still have the same problem. Names in the blue box are fine but in the red box some of characters are missing. (Image)- https://ibb.co/nN3xEb

Comment: @indritleka The issue with the red box seems to be caused by limit of the text field. Will you double-check the length of the field? If my visual counting is correct, it is set to 10 characters.

Comment: Yes you was precise since the first expression. Both of them works perfectly. I was inattentive at the text limit field option.Thank you